# RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeIdentifier Equivalent in netstandard2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

Is there a `RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeIdentifier` equivalent in netstandard2.0? How would i get the runtime identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Operating​System.​Platform`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operatingsystem.platform?view=netstandard-2.0

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.OSVersion.Platform
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operatingsystem?view=netstandard-2.0[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operatingsystem?view=netstandard-2.0)